# PayPal credit card payment option

Tags: paypal

I am confused on one simple situation is that when I have already created PayPal BuyNow button and I suppose to see the credit card details' form when I come to PayPal login page, but there is only the link 'continue checkout', so does anyone know how to automatically redirect to the page with credit card details' input form?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your cookies and try again. It's because it knows you have a PayPal account.

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking on the check and the up arrow, that is if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Do check if you are logged into paypal. If you are logged into paypal the credit card entry would not be shown.

Comment: Even if you are logged out, I have noticed that you still get that screen. They have some kind of persistent cookies. At least they used to when I was using their API.